# Trying to close a div from another div

Tags: jquery, html

I have created a listings page where each listing has its own div, the content for that div is loaded from a separate php script via a $.post

**The problem I have is trying to hide the listing, I think the problem may be something to do with this line**

$('div.close_listing')

only I can get it to work if I use

```
$('div.listing> div').click(  
function() {
$('div.listing> div').hide(); 
});
```

(which works when I click anywhere in the listing div)

Any help much appreciated.

The html code for the listing is:

```
<div id='listing'>
   <div id='loading'></div>
   <a name='13'><h3>Business1</h3></a> <h4 data-id=18-3-3>Name Of Business 1</h4>
    <div>
        <hr>
     *** content forbusiness1 appears here ***
          <div class='close_listing'>CLOSE this listing</div>
    </div>

   <a name='14'><h3>Business2</h3></a> <h4 data-id=19-3-3>Name Of Business 2</h4>
    <div>
        <hr>
     *** content for business2 appears here ***
          <div class='close_listing'>CLOSE this listing</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

The code to call the content is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('div.listing> div').hide();  
$('div.listing> h4').click(function() {
$('div.listing> div').empty().html('<img src="loading_image.gif" /><br>Retrieving Details.....');
$.post("http://www.example.com/record.php", { id: $(this).attr('data-id') });

$.post('show.php',{ id: $(this).attr('data-id')}, function(data) {
$('div.listing> div').html(data); 

$('div.listing .close').visible();
});

var $nextDiv = $(this).next();
var $visibleSiblings = $nextDiv.siblings('div:visible');

if ($visibleSiblings.length ) {
  $visibleSiblings.slideUp('fast', function() {
    $nextDiv.slideToggle('fast');
  });
} else {
   $nextDiv.slideToggle('fast');
} 
});

// closes the listing down

$('div.close_listing').click(  
function() {
$('div.listing> div').hide(); 
}); 

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it a bit difficult to understand your question, but if what you want is to close the close_listing parent div then I have edited your html markup like so

```
 <div id='listing'>
   <div id='loading'></div>
   <a name='13'><h3>Business1</h3></a> <h4 data-id=18-3-3>Name Of Business 1</h4>
    <div>
        <hr>
     content forbusiness1 appears here
          <a class='close_listing'  href="#">
            CLOSE this listing
          </a>
    </div>

   <a name='14'><h3>Business2</h3></a> <h4 data-id=19-3-3>Name Of Business 2</h4>
    <div>
        <hr>
      content for business2 appears here

           <a class='close_listing'  href="#">
            CLOSE this listing
          </a>
    </div>

</div>
```

The the javascript should be like so

$('a.close_listing').bind('click', function () {

```
    $(this).parent().show().fadeOut(500);
            return false;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Mark - that worked a treat. Please could you explain how it works?

Comment: Leo the div containing the content for business is a parent to the anchor link, so to get the div object you use parent, there is also siblings which is child to an element. If you have any question pls feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you intended to do this

```
$('div.close_listing').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('.listing').hide(); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Interstellar_coder - that doesn't seem to work - you can try out the page by visiting:

http://www.dadni.co.uk/m_search_test.php

Select restaurants and then indian and the results will appear.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
$('div.listing> div').hide();
```

It should be

```
$('div#listing > div').hide();
```

But I think then you are hiding to much (all the divs directly below #listing). Consider the following:

```
$(this).parent().hide();
```